# C++ Pointer to another point

Tags: c++, pointers

Current I have pointers working for my two object pointers e.g.

```
Object * obj1;
Object * obj2;

obj2 = obj2;
```

How would I get this to work if I had

```
Object * array[10][10];
Object * newarray[10][10];
```

Could I assign array to newarray without using a for loop to cyle through elements?

Asking because I have my main class which has the array in it.
This is then passed to a sub class so that it can be worked on, a copy needs to be saved in the new class so it can be accessed by the sub classes functions.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, use `std::array`. While you're at it, you might want to switch to smart pointers if they're managing memory.

Comment: Maybe [`std::uninitialized_fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill).

Comment: @0x499602D2: You mean `std::uninitialized_copy`, right? Personally, I'd prefer `std::copy` here. `uninitialized_copy` just so happens to work because we're talking about trivial types here, but I would prefer the normal `copy` because it's consistent with what you would do if the type were non-trivial. The `uninitialized_...` functions are for special purposes where you are trying to *construct* objects in uninitialized memory. We don't really want construction here, we want assignment (though with trivial types, there's no difference after optimization), and that's what `std::copy` is for.

Comment: `Could I assign array to newarray without using a for loop to cyle through elements?` no, because `array[10][10]` is not a pointer it's a 2-dim array of pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object * array[10][10];` is **not** a pointer to an array of 10x10 Objects. It is an array of 10x10 pointers to objects.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Object {};
Object * arr[10][10];
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "sizeof arr = " << sizeof(arr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

produces
sizeof arr1 = 400

If you want to stick with C-like behavior, you could use memcpy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct Object {};
Object * arr1[10][10];
Object * arr2[10][10];

...

memcpy(arr1, arr2, sizeof(arr1));
```

If you want to take a C++ approach, as others have said, take a look at std::array or std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

Kfsone's solution serves the purpose. following sample code illustrates this. Wanted to post in comment to his post however, then code would have been unreadable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int *x1[2][2];
    int *x2[2][2];

    int a1 = 100;
    int b1 = 101;
    int c1 = 110;
    int d1 = 111;


    int a2 = 200;
    int b2 = 201;
    int c2 = 210;
    int d2 = 211;

    x1[0][0] = &a1;
    x1[0][1] = &b1;
    x1[1][0] = &c1;
    x1[1][1] = &d1;


    x2[0][0] = &a2;
    x2[0][1] = &b2;
    x2[1][0] = &c2;
    x2[1][1] = &d2;

    memcpy(x1,x2,sizeof(x2));
    printf("%d\n",*x1[1][1]);

    return 1;
}
```